# Load Json file components into Aframe via URL

Tags: json, url, model, aframe

I'm trying to load a terrain model from a json file via an url to my aframe scene. I'm using the code from another project and I can't understand how to get the json file url with the same format as they did:

```
/* global AFRAME, THREE */
AFRAME.registerComponent('ground', {
  schema: {
    url: { default: 'https://cdn.aframe.io/link-traversal/models/ground.json' }
  },
  update: function () {
    var objectLoader;
    var self = this;
    if (this.objectLoader) { return; }
    objectLoader = this.objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
    objectLoader.setCrossOrigin('');
    objectLoader.load(this.data.url, function (obj) {
      obj.children.forEach(function (value) {
        if (value instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
          value.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
          value.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
          value.receiveShadow = true;
          value.material.shading = THREE.FlatShading;
        }
      });
      self.el.setObject3D('ground', obj);
    });
  }
});
```

How can I get my json file url in the same format [and show this when opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH4XD.png)?

Comment: how do You get the linked JSON params window ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the file needs to be served over the https protocol, or You won't be able to get the file from the link.

If You want to get a CDN.(....) link to a JSON file, You need to upload it on github, and paste the URL to the file on [rawgit](https://rawgit.com/), where You will get Your CDN link.

You can also try [glitch.me](https://glitch.com/), where You can upload Your assets to a project.

If You have Your own hosting, just link it locally: `/modelDirectory/jsonfile.json`

I quite don't get the 'same format' part, If You're asking how to covert a model to JSON, the easiest way is to upload it to clara.io, and download the three.js JSON export files. Other than that, You can find some exporters which need to be implemented into blender, like the original threejs [one](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender).

Comment: I have my json file on github. I've tried rawgit as you've mentioned but when I link it in my project it doesn't work and so I opened the CDN link and I get an error (404: not found).
I'm using glitch as well but I cannot load the model textures therefore I'm trying to use a json file.

Comment: Figured out why I got the 404 error. My github rep was private. Had to change to public. The link is still not producing the model into my scene on glitch but perhaps that's because of the code. I used the three js exporter to create my json file from blender. But I think the components are not the same as the variables used in the code above. That might be the issue.